# Magento API product URL not updating

Tags: php, api, magento

'm using Magento API with SOAP, and what I'm trying to achieve is to show the products from my page in an external webpage. I'm showing ID, name, description, image and a link to the page. Everything works fine, except for one thing: The links to the products page are all the same (they all redirect to the first product)

This is my code so far:

```
<?php
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://127.0.0.1/magento/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
$sessionId = $proxy->login('testUser', 'password'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary
$pageURL="categorytree.php/";
$result = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId);
//var_dump($result);

echo "<br><br>";

require_once('/magento/app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
//var_dump($productModel->getProductUrl);

foreach($result as $product)
{
    echo "ID: $product->product_id <br>";
    $productID = $product->product_id;
    echo "Name: $product->name <br>";
    $p = $productModel->load($productID);
    $description = $p->getDescription();
    echo "Description: $description <br>";
    $imageUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $p->getImage();
    $product_collection_url = $p->getProductUrl();
    $product_collection_url = str_replace($pageURL,"",$product_collection_url);
    echo "Image: <a href='$product_collection_url'><img src='$imageUrl'></a><br>";
    echo "<a href='$product_collection_url'>link to page</a><br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
echo "<br><br>";
?>
```

First I thought it had something to do with the for loop, but each product id, name, description is correct, $product_collection_url is the one causing trouble.

It looks like $p->getProductUrl only works the first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, solved it.

I had to load the product again, adding these lines

```
$my_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID); 
$my_product_url = $my_product->getProductUrl();
```

to get the url to the product page